# realVNC very slow, what is the bottle neck if the network is fast?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, remote, vnc

I hope this is the right place where to ask this.

Background: I need to connect remotely to a Cents OS 7 server from my ubuntu 18.04 and to use a GUI, but not concerned with image quality: just need a refresh rate decent enough to code and visualize (zoom in/out) some graphs. Also, I am not the admin of the server, I'm stick with what is installed there.

Connection speeds are:

- client: ~80mbps download and upload, 4ms ping
- server: ~800mbps dowload and upload, 1ms ping

I tried realVNC and tigervnc (tigernvc-viewer) on the client and tigervnc 1.8.0 is installed on the server.

Even with image quality set to low and server load low there is significant lag. One strange thing is that the lag is higher when scrolling in sublime text editor than when doing it in firefox.

Any hint?